# How do I examine whether the resting positions are attractive or repulsive?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I determine all the rest positions for the following scalar differential equation $x'= x^2-μ,x ∈ R$ as a function of the parameter $μ ∈ R$.

$x'=x^2-μ$

The rest positions are when $x’=0$, and thus $x^2_{rest}−μ=0$. There are two solutions to this equation $x_{rest}=±\sqrt{μ}$. If $μ≥0$ there are two real rest positions, but if $μ<0$ the rest positions are imaginary.

How do I examine whether the resting positions are attractive or repulsive?